# If the code is in the database I need it to generate a random number

Tags: php, pdo

```
require("inc/connection.php");
if ($link->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error: '.$link->connect_errno.': '.$link->connect_error);
$insertedcode = $_POST['code'];
$results = $link->query("SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = :code");
$query_params = array( 
    ':code' => $_POST['code']
);

$stmt = $link->prepare($results);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row) {
    $number = mt_rand(0,3999);
    echo $number;
}
```

This is what I have I think I have the random number part down. But for some reason it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\dashboard.php on line 21

It wont execute and Im not sure why.

Comment: Print $stmt after this line, it seems null. $stmt = $link->prepare($results);

Comment: nothing happens when i print $stmt.

Comment: That's null indeed then :)

Comment: How do I fix it if its nulled I am new to php :(

Comment: Your should prepare the SQL query, not the result

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it in wrong order on the code that uses mysqli, right? If you query without actual params assigned to code, it's the reason. Prepare the query before querying, not after.

```
 require("inc/connection.php");
    if ($link->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error: '.$link->connect_errno.': '.$link->connect_error);
    $insertedcode = $_POST['code'];
    //$results = $link->query("SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = :code");
    $query_string = "SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = :code";
    $query_params = array( 
        ':code' => $_POST['code']
    );

    $stmt = $link->prepare($query_string);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $query_params[':code']);
    $result = $stmt->execute(); //$query_params is only in procedural, read the manual
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) {
        $number = mt_rand(0,3999);
        echo $number;
    }
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: try to replace the lines starting with $stmt = ... with $stmt  = $link->prepare("SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = 'some test code' "); $stmt->execute(); and tell me what happened

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the SQL string to `prepare`, and therefore it is useless to do the `query` call:

```
// skip next line
//$results = $link->query("SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = :code");
$query_params = array( 
    ':code' => $_POST['code']
);

// Use SQL as argument here, not $results
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = :code");
```

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object